# Classifying black and silver images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am struggling to classify the images at black and silver colores
How can I use OpenCV in order to classify them? Image with black color Image with Silver color?
What error is there below ?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


# RGB color boundaries
black = ([0, 0, 0], [50, 50, 50])

boundaries = [black]

# 
# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('zmFf4.jpg')
print(img.shape)

breakpoint()
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:

    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")


    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
    # the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    # show the images
    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking the silver range
Do as under

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


# RGB color boundaries
black = ([0, 0, 0], [50, 50, 50])
silver = ([192, 192, 192], [212, 212, 212])
boundaries = [black, silver]

#
# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('zmFf4.jpg')
print(img.shape)

breakpoint()
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:

    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")


    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
    # the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    # show the images
    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: @Umar Khalid, hope this help solve your issue and you can see this